# Is there a way to shorten this SLIDER WIDTH code?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am making a script for this slider that will change according to the number that is written in the input.

I made it pretty easy and simple but I am wondering if there is any way to shorten this? Like set 100% of the slider to be number 10 and 0 to be 0% and let the magic happen in between.

Here is the code

```
    var f = $("#meter .container .fill");
    var i = $("#meter input#nbr");

i.keyup(function() {        
        if(i.val() == 10) {
            f.animate({width: "100%"}, 500);
        }
        else if(i.val() == 9){
            f.animate({width: "90%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 8){
            f.animate({width: "80%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 7){
            f.animate({width: "70%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 6){
            f.animate({width: "60%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 5){
            f.animate({width: "50%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 4){
            f.animate({width: "40%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 3){
            f.animate({width: "30%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 2){
            f.animate({width: "20%"}, 500);
        }

        else if(i.val() == 1){
            f.animate({width: "10%"}, 500);
        }
    });
```

As I said, everything works as expected, I am just wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use `f.animate({width: i.val() + "0%"}, 500);`

Comment: You could put the input / percentage pairs into an array and use the array to control the animation. EDIT: the difference to Sushil's solution is that you could use percentages that are not calculated from the input.

Comment: omg thanks! I can not believe this did not come to my mind! Danke!!!!